# Linkedin groups API - receive Job Title / Company Title?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using IN RAW API Calls to receive details of group posts. How about Job Title and Company Title of group contributors? Industry works btw.

best

M

```
IN.API.Raw("posts/{post-id}/comments:(creator:(first- name,last-name,picture-url,industry),id,creation-timestamp,text)?count=5&start=0")
 .method("GET")
 .result(function success(results) {
 console.log(results);
 })
.error(function error(e) {
console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the info in a JSON object that describes the positions of the creator but you'll have to parse that as done here with `curl` and `jq`, broken down for readability:

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}"
    "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/{post-id}
        /comments:(creator:(positions:(title,company)))?&format=json" |
    jq -r '
        .values[0].creator.positions.values[0].title,
        .values[0].creator.positions.values[0].company.name'
```

Comment: Thank you I was looking for this creator:(positions:(title,company) in the groups API